# Add two elements in a dataframe (based on the index)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe in which some rows are useless except for one variable.
I want to add that the variable in those rows to the previous row and then delete the useless rows.

In the data frame there are some rows in which the only useful information is on a variable, so I want to preserve this information.
More precisely, my dataframe looks something like

```py
|cat1| cat2|var1|var2|
|A   |x    |1   |2   |
|A   |x    |1   |0   |
|A   |x    |.   |5   |
|A   |y    |1   |2   |
|A   |y    |1   |2   |
|A   |y    |1   |3   |
|A   |y    |.   |6   |
|B   |x    |1   |2   |
|B   |x    |1   |4   |
|B   |x    |1   |2   |
|B   |x    |1   |1   |
|B   |x    |.   |3   |
```

and i want to get

```py
|cat1| cat2|var1|var2|
|A   |x    |1   |2     |
|A   |x    |1   |5(5+0)|
|A   |y    |1   |2     |
|A   |y    |1   |2     |
|A   |y    |1   |9(6+3)|
|B   |x    |1   |2     |
|B   |x    |1   |4     |
|B   |x    |1   |2     |
|B   |x    |1   |4(3+1)|
```

iI've tried code like

```py
test = df[df['var1'] == '.'].index
for num in test:
    df['var2][num - 1] = df['var2][num - 1] + df['var2][num]
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it true there are never 2 consecutive `.`s?

Comment: No, there are never two consecutive '.'

Answer (score 1):

For a very readable solution combine [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to select the rows where the [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed rows of `var1` contain `.`. Use the `-1` to select the *next* row. If that's the case add the next row, otherwise just fill the original row. Afterwards, just drop all the rows with a `.`

```
df['var2_new'] = np.where(df['var1'].shift(-1) == '.', 
                          df['var2'] + df['var2'].shift(-1), df['var2'])
df[df['var1'] != '.']
#   cat1 cat2 var1  var2  var2_new
#0     A    x    1     2       2.0
#1     A    x    1     0       5.0
#3     A    y    1     2       2.0
#4     A    y    1     2       2.0
#5     A    y    1     3       9.0
#7     B    x    1     2       2.0
#8     B    x    1     4       4.0
#9     B    x    1     2       2.0
#10    B    x    1     1       4.0
```

Comment: This solved my problem and is indeed very readable. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Pandas also supports `df.where` command similar to numpy. Why don't you use pandas `df.where` instead of numpy? Is there any advantage in using numpy `np.where` over pandas `df.where`?